# Connectedness of product topology: Flawed proof

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Suppose $X_i$ is a connected topological space $\forall i \in I$ an arbitrary index set. I want to show that $X := \prod_{i \in I}  X_i$ is connected. My "proof" must contain a simple error since it only seems to need the fact that one of the $X_i$ is connected, but at the moment I am struggling to see the problem:

Suppose $U, V$ are open in $X$ such that $X = U \cup V$. We want to show that $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$.

The projection map $\pi_j: X \to X_j \space; \pi_j(x)=x_j$ is continuous and open.

$X_j = \pi_j(X) = \pi_j(U \cup V) = \pi_j(U) \cup \pi_j(V) =: U_j \cup V_j$

Now, due to the openness of $\pi_j$ and the connectedness of $X_j$ it follows that $U_j \cap V_j \neq \emptyset$. Also, $\pi_j$ is surjective and therefore:

$\emptyset \neq \pi_j^{-1}(U_j \cap V_j) = \pi_j^{-1}(U_j) \cap \pi_j^{-1}(V_j) = U \cap V$

I'd be happy if someone could quickly point to the error in my reasoning but I do not need an actual proof to the statement.

Comment: If $f$ is surjective, $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$; if $f$ is injective, $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined $U_j$ as $\pi_j(U)$. It does *not* follow from this that $U=\pi_j^{-1}(U_j)$, as you have assumed implicitly near the end. In fact, $U$ can be distinct from $\pi_j^{-1}(U_j)$.

As an example, consider $\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}$, which is disconnected (I am assuming that I am working with the usual topologies on $\Bbb R$ and on $\{0,1\}$). Take $U=\Bbb R\times\{0\}$ and $V=\Bbb R\times\{1\}$. Then $\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}=U\cup V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$. On the other hand, $\pi_1(U)=\pi_1(V)=\Bbb R$. So, $U_1=V_1=\Bbb R$. But$$\pi_1^{-1}(U_1)=\pi_1^{-1}(\Bbb R)=\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}\varsupsetneq U.$$